# Strange (unknown) MySql Behaviour

Tags: mysql, database

Ok , consider I have a Database  with one table call it Table A . 
Table A  Have Id int ,sum int.
Supose I want the sum values of table A that are greater than the Average of sum values.

For this I made two queries :

```
SELECT
    a.id
FROM
    TableA a,
    (SELECT AVG(sum) AS mes FROM TableA) b
WHERE
    a.sum>b.mes;


SELECT
    a.id
FROM
    TableA a
WHERE
    a.sum > (SELECT AVG(a.sum))
GROUP BY
    a.id;
```

The way I see it these queries are the same , but the result is Ok for the first and Null for the second.

My question is simple , is there a logic error in second query? If yes , can someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes those two queries are not equal. because in first query you are treating them as two individual tables and get the result set and finally compare it.

but in second query your performing aggregate  function in that case you  will get average for individual a.id

execute this you will understand what i mean

```
Select a.id from TableA a where a.sum = (Select avg(a.sum)) group by a.id;
```

Comment: So it means that in the second query I compare a Result set from a table with another table and not with its result set?

Comment: in the second query your using group by so it will group using a.id and then take average of each group so that average will get equal to its value

Comment: @HasS please check and let me know

Comment: That is true , i made a simple test trying to compare for greater or equal to its value  and the result is all values obtained from the group by clause , same as you explained above :D Thnx for your answer